# Axios get URL parameter string not accepted

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios, ecmascript-2017

Why do I get error:

> "The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined"

when I run this code:
P.S. I also tried to pass in variable with this URL, but the result was the same.

```
var axios = require('axios')();

module.exports = {
    async getJSONAsync(){


        let json = await axios.get('https://tutorialzine.com/misc/files/example.json');

        return json;
    }
};
```

NOTE: I use this function in another async function with await keyword. 
Like :

```
async begin() {

        try {
            let setup = new SetUp(this.bot);
            await testapi.getJSONAsync().then(function (json) {
                console.log(json)
            });
            let settings = await setup.prepareTest();
            let session = await settings.driver.getSession();
            logger.logDebug('Launching ' + this.test.name);

            return settings;
        }

        catch (e) {

            logger.logErr('Error when create settings for ' + this.test.name);
            throw e;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  require('axios')()
```

That will import axios and directly calls it with the no argument at all, therefore it will complain as the url it expects is not passed. Maybe just dont call it here?

Comment: So should I use like:

var axios = require('axios');
var app = axios;

and then call app.get?

Comment: @littleJohnny jup.

Comment: I'm new here, so may I ask why should I use app variable?

Comment: @littleJohnny you dont have to. Thats completely up to you. You could also do `require("axios").get("somurl")` or something similar. Or `const axios = require("axios"); axios.get("someurl")` or...

Comment: And how can I parse my response? In which function? Like "Begin" or "Json"?

Comment: @littleJohnny glad to help :)

Comment: One more question - if I use const axios = require("axios");  and then axios.get(someUrl) -WebStorm IDE says 'get' is unresolved. Any ideas why?

Comment: @littleJohnny nope